# How is it best to add properties to an object literal in JS?

Tags: javascript

I was learning JS and came across two ways to add properties to object literal. The first is straightforward: `let person ={name:"Ben", age:5}`. The second way is `let person ={}; person.name="Ben"; person.age=5`. The question is Is the second way of adding new properties is acceptable and does it have some, maybe, performance issues?

Comment: Most likely you will never notice any performance problem unless you create A LOT of objects that way. And if you do that, most likely there something else wrong in how you approach the problem.

Comment: @Sirko, so basically we can use either way with no problems. Is that right?

Comment: As a beginner yes and chances are that in all the code you will write this never has any impact.

Comment: Opinion based question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second method may be *very slightly* inefficient, at least in V8, due to its use of [hidden classes](https://richardartoul.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/04/26/hidden-classes.html).

> Every time a new property is added to an object, the objects old hidden class is updated with a transition path to the new hidden class.

With the second method, you have:

- the empty `person`
- Then you add the `.name` property: the hidden class of `person` switches from being empty to having `name` (which is created by the engine if it doesn't exist already)
- Then you add the `age` property: the hidden class of `person` switches again, from having `name` to having both `name` and `age`.

In contrast, with the first method, the compiler can *immediately* see that the `person` object will always start with exactly two properties: `name` and `age`, rather than having to switch to a new hidden class every time a property is added.

> **Adding properties to an object after instantiation will force a hidden class change** and slow down any methods that were optimized for the previous hidden class.

That said - unless this sort of thing is being done in a *very tight* loop, the performance impact will almost certainly be completely unnoticeable. Computers can carry out millions of calculations per second, after all. Better to write *clean, readable* code, and only optimize for performance if you run a performance test and notice that a part of your code is taking up too many resources.

(but, even still, IMO declaring the object all at once is probably preferable - code is easier to read and understand when unnecessary mutation is avoided)